# Text recognition in Android

Tags: android, whatsapp, text-recognition

I want to automate Whatsapp message sending process(Android). For that I want to use text recognition feature once the Whatsapp is fired from an implicit intent to recognize particular group name to which I want to send that msg.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do the way I am thinking?
2. What can be used to do text/image detection?
3. Once the implicit intent is fired which app controls the particular poped up activity?How the control transfer process happens?

Comment: Since there is no WhatsApp API for Android (as Codeteddy mentions in his answer) you could take a look at Telegram or Viber.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an app that is able to recognize some text or a qr-code. But the issue is that there is **no** (official) **WhatsApp API for Android** where you can send a message with a specific text to a specific person or group.

You are able to send a specific text, but you still need to select the person you want to receive this message. This makes WhatsApp texting not faster.

There are a lot of optical character recognition software, short OCR, you could use for that.